# Issue with mocking http => returns observable in Angular 7

Tags: angular, observable, angular-http-interceptors

I have an HTTP Interceptor in my angular app where I want to simply return mock data if a certain endpoint is called instead of actually going to the server.

It seems like there's an issue with my observable code as I do not get any errors, but the `.subscribe` function is not executed. I'm not quite sure what might be happening since I'm not getting any errors.

**HttpInterceptor**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {DemoHttpServer} from './demo-http-server';

@Injectable()
export class DemoHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private demoHttpServer: DemoHttpServer) {

  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (request.url.startsWith('https://demo.company.com/api/')) {
      return this.demoHttpServer.handle(request);
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

**Demo HTTP Server**

```
handle(req: HttpRequest<any>): Observable<any> {
    const result = {isMock: true};

    return Observable.create((observer: Subscriber<any>) => {
      observer.next(result);
      observer.complete();
    });
  }
```

In My Component

```
http.get('https://demo.company.com/api/counts')
.subscribe(data => {
  // never get in here..., don't get any console errors
})
```

Comment: Also, which version of RxJS are you using? The current import should be this: `import {Observable} from 'rxjs';`

Comment: In looking into this further, the observer.next is expecting to an Observable<HttpResponse>, not a simple object. See this: https://dev.to/sanidz/angular-http-mock-interceptor-for-mocked-backend-1h5g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code and the post I mentioned in the comments, I built an interceptor like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class DemoInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (req.url.startsWith('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')) {
      const mockToDos = [{
        userId: 1,
        id: 99,
        title: 'test',
        completed: false
      }];

      return of(new HttpResponse({
        status: 200, body: mockToDos
      }));
    }

    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Notice that it returns an `Observable<HttpResponse>`.

You can find the working blitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mock-interceptor-deborahk

For your scenario, the code would look more like this:

```
    if (req.url.startsWith('https://demo.company.com/api/')) {
      const mockData = mockBody;

      return of(new HttpResponse({
        status: 200, body: mockBody
      }));
    }
```

Comment: Oh I'm such a dummy.... it was the end of the day, my brain was fried. Thank you Deborak!